# AWS EBS Snapshot to EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-efs

We are in the process of migrating from EBS to EFS for our data storage solution. We are having Terabytes of data. Currently we are mounting the EFS to the same EC2 instance and running a copying/rsync operation to copy data from EBS to EFS.

Just wanted to know if there is a way to restore a EBS Snapshot directly to EFS so complete data set goes to EFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mounting the EFS to the same EC2 instance and running a copying/rsync
>   operation to copy data from EBS to EFS

Looks like this is the only available/feasible option.

Comment: rsync makes it possible to do a delta sync and you end up with consistent data so apparently it should be preferred to cp.

Comment: Yes @SebK, that's what we followed and looks like it's still the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, the only option is to attach the EFS to the EC2 instances and copy or rsync the data.

You are already doing this. You may want to write a script to perform these operations across all your EBS volumes to help speed up the process.